# Firestore get all field inside docId based on list uid from other collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem to get value from `users` based on uid in `locations` collection

My `locations` collection is something like this:

[image]

where the `docId` is generated based on user `uid`, here i want to fetch all `locations` data **and** get detail of which `uid` belongs to

and my `users` collection contain this structure in each `docId`:

```
{
  "birthday": "12 02 2023",
  "coordinates": {
    "latitude": -6.16927,
    "longitude": 106.6233983
  },
  "createdAt": 1676137787,
  "gender": 1,
  "img": "imgURL",
  "lastOnline": {
    "nanoseconds": 72000000,
    "seconds": 1676194717
  },
  "name": "Flix",
}
```

I've tried using `where in` but it's not suitable because `where in` is limited to 10

```
const getAllUser = async () => {
  const usersRef = firestore().collection('users');
  const locationsRef = firestore().collection('locations');
  let locationQuery = await locationsRef.get();
  const listUsersInLocation = [];
  locationQuery.forEach((data, i) => {
    listUsersInLocation.push(data.id); //store docId (user uid) of locations
  });
  let usersQuery = await usersRef.where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', listUsersInLocation).get();
  usersQuery.forEach(x => {
    console.log(x.data());
  });
};
```

I'm expecting to get location and user information, so is there any other way to fetch `locations` + `users` based on list of `uid`? or should i redesign my collection structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your data model you need to fetch each doc of the `users` collection, as follows (untested). Note that since we want to execute, in parallel, a variable number of queries to the `users` collection we use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```js
const getAllUser = async () => {
    const usersRef = firestore().collection('users');
    const locationsRef = firestore().collection('locations');
    let locationQuerySnap = await locationsRef.get();

    const listUsersInLocationPromises = [];
    locationQuerySnap.forEach((data) => {
        listUsersInLocationPromises.push(usersRef.doc(data.id).get());
    });
    let usersDocSnaphotsArray = await Promise.all(listUsersInLocationPromises);

    // At this stage we have two arrays whith the same number of elements
    // and THE SAME ORDER (see the Promise.all() documentation)

    // locationQuerySnap.docs is the array of all the Locations DocumentSnapshots
    // usersDocSnaphotsArray is the array of all the Users DocumentSnapshots

    // So you can, for example, do as follows
    usersDocSnaphotsArray.forEach((doc, idx) => {
        console.log(doc.data());
        console.log(locationQuerySnap.docs[idx].data());
    });
    // Or any other operation on the two arrays, e.g. merging them

};
```

---

If you have a one-to-one relationship between a `user` and a `location` you may want to merge the two data sets in one document. This depends on the queries you execute from your app. If you rarely execute the above composed query (i.e. users AND locations) but often list users OR locations you can keep your current model.

Comment: i'm concern about *fetch each doc of the users collection*, if i have 20 data in `locations` does it mean my `usage` in firestore increase 21 times (1 for get location, 20 for get each user) each time executing `getAllUser()`?

Comment: Not sure to undertnd what you mean by "my usage in firestore increase 21 times". What I can confirm is that for each location document you query the user document corresponding to the location ID. So I would say that each location generates two reads (one for the location doc and one for the user doc). This is why I wrote the paragraph about one-to-one relationship between a user and a location at the end of my answer: there may be some room for data model optimisation. But as of now we don't have enough info to give some guidance.